# Stored procedure hints for insert records from query out

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a newbie and only have some basic knowledge of SQL, can you please teach me how to write this in a stored procedure?

Firstly, I want to get a max id from a table

```
SELECT MAX(ID) 
FROM groups
```

Then together with the result from the same table

```
select id，user_id 
from groups 
where group_id =11
```

insert all the records in a loop into the same table with increasing maxid

```
insert into groups 
values (maxid + 1, @id, @user_id, 33)
```

Thank you,
Jeff

Comment: Also: **DON'T DO THIS!** Don't do a "SELECT MAX()" and then do a "+ 1" manually - this will **definitely** result in duplicate values being inserted! You should let the **database** itself handle this using an `INT IDENTITY` column .....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a procedure for that. Just a single query

```
insert into groups 
select (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM groups), id，user_id 
from groups 
where group_id = 11
```

BTW you should name the columns you insert into:

```
insert into groups (col1, col2, ...)
```

Also what Marc_s wrote: Let the DB generate IDs for you.